# Hive shell throws Filenotfound exception while executing queries, inspite of adding jar files using "ADD JAR"

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

1) I have added   serde jar file  using "ADD JAR   /home/hduser/softwares/hive/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;"

2) Create table

3) The table is creates successfully

4) But when I execute any select query it throws file not found exception

```
hive> select count(*) from tab_tweets;

Query ID = hduser_20150604145353_51b4def4-11fb-4638-acac-77301c1c1806
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://node1:9000/home/hduser/softwares/hive/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1638)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:754)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File does not exist: hdfs://node1:9000/home/hduser/softwares/hive/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Comment: hive> list jars  // try this it should return the jar files you added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**METHOD 1:** Copy `hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` file from local filesystem to HDFS.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /home/hduser/softwares/hive/
hadoop fs -put /home/hduser/softwares/hive/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/hduser/softwares/hive/
```

> **Note:** Use **hdfs dfs** instead of **hadoop fs**, if you are using latest hadoop versions.

**METHOD 2:** Change the value for `hive.aux.jars.path` in `hive-site.xml` as:

```
<property>
 <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
 <value>file:///home/hduser/softwares/hive/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</value>
</property>
```

**METHOD 3:** Add `hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` in hadoop classpath. i.e., add this line in `hadoop-env.sh`:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/home/hduser/softwares/hive/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

> **NOTE:** I have mentioned the paths considering you have installed hive in **/home/hduser/softwares/hive**. If you have hive installed
>   elsewhere, please change **/home/hduser/softwares/hive** to point to
>   your hive installation folder.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, I have tried Method3 and Method2 and it didn't work. Then I copied the file to the hdfs path with directory structure as mentioned in the hive.aux.jar.path. It woked like a charm after that. Thanks you so  much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check jar exists at /home/hduser/softwares/hive/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 0):

**Note: No need to copy the hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in to hdfs, keep it in local Fs itself.**

At Query execution time. Hive will take care of it making available in all nodes as D.C

Refer this link for details : [official link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli)

**FYI - refer Hive Resources**

Once a resource is added to a session, Hive queries can refer to it by its name (in map/reduce/transform clauses)
and the resource is available locally at execution time on the entire Hadoop cluster.
Hive uses Hadoop's Distributed Cache to distribute the added resources to all the machines in the cluster at query execution time

*you can add additional Jars in multipe ways:*

- **for current hive session**:

> hive > add jar /local/fs/path/to/your/file.jar
>
> hive > list jars   //-- to check

- **Adding on the node from which you are running hive in .hiverc like .bashrc**

  cd $HOME

  create a file .hiverc

  cat $HOME/.hiverc

  add jar /local/fs/path/to/your/file.jar  // add this line
- **Adding jar file to hive-site.xml**

  hive.aux.jars.path
   file:///home/user/path/to/your/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar