# Hive jar does not exist

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am running Hive on localhost and my query is throwing error:

Everything is working fine with commands like `select`,`insert` and `create`, but it is throwing error for those queries where `group by` or `joins` are used.
Below is the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1085)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1085)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:559)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1858)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1072)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar
```

It is saying the file does not exist but the file is the place. Below is the snap of bashrc for hive:

```
#hive installation
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Similar issue have been solved in the below question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647741/hive-shell-throws-filenotfound-exception-while-executing-queries-inspite-of-add

Comment: But it was  working fine few days ago. I didn't change any conf file of hadoop or hive. It was using the jar present in localfs. 
Still i will try the resolution provide in the link and will update ASAP.

Comment: I tried the methods provided in that link but nothing works. Finally I tried removing the 'hive.aux.jars.path' property from hive-site.xml and now it is working normally.